# .net mvc host header injection - http module - 400 Bad Request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule, header-injection

I have a task to mitigate host header injection in an MVC app.  Among other things, I want to implement a whitelist check by creating a HTTP Module.

So far, I am using something like this:

web.config entry:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="TestHttpModule" type="MVC5TestApp.MyHttpModule, MVC5TestApp" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

HTTP Module class:

```
public class MyHttpModule: IHttpModule 
{

    public MyHttpModule() {}

    public void Init(HttpApplication application) 
    {
        application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.context_BeginRequest);
        application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(this.context_EndRequest);
    }

    public void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        CheckForHostHeaderInjection();
    }

    public void context_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // some code
    }

    public void Dispose() {}

    private void CheckForHostHeaderInjection()
    {
        // Currently, I am just comparing the following two ServerVariables.
        // I will add a method to compare "HTTP_HOST" value against a whitelist later.
        var httpHost = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
        var serverName = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];

        if (!string.Equals(httpHost, serverName))
        {
            // What do I do in order to send back to the client a 400 Bad Request??
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For MVC, the cleaner solution would be to implement an `IActionFilter` to perform your validation. In `OnActionExecuting` you can perform your header checks and force the response (your HTTP 400) there to short circuit the rest of the request flow.

Your `OnActionExecuting` implementation would look like the following.

```
if(!ValidateWhiteListedHeaders(context.HttpContext.Request.Headers)){
  context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(400);
  return;
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs#understanding-action-filters

Comment: I had considered this approach as well and will follow up on it.  Do you know the best way to force the HTTP 400?